# Creating Inline Style Sheet With Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hihi. I'm trying to create an inline style sheet at the beginning of the page which reacts to what i'm GETTING from the url. Im doing this so I can have the navbutton of the page that im on highlighted. Kind of like here, www.myeg.net , but they have a static site and it is much easier.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function parseUrl( url ) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    return a;
}

var page=parseUrl('').search

function getSecondPart(str) {
    return str.split('=')[1];
}

var site=getSecondPart(page);

var style = document.createElement("style");
style.innerHTML = ".nav_" + page + " { background-image:url('images/gradients/transparent_gradient.png');}";
document.body.appendChild(style);


}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center><div><img width="960px" height="187.5" src="images/fullbanner.png"></div></center>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="navbar">
<ul>
<li class="nav_index"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li class="nav_archive"><a href="index.php?site=news&action=archive">News</a></li>
<li class="nav_squads"><a href="index.php?site=squads">Roster</a></li>
<li class="nav_forum"><a href="index.php?site=forum">Forums</a></li>
<li class="nav_about"><a href="index.php?site=about">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm pretty noob at javascript so sorry ;;;

Comment: Also I know thett way im setting it up now nav_archive and nav_index might not work because the URL is slightly different. I wonder if theres a simple way to select the last GET parameter from the URL

Comment: Are these pages being dynamically generated by (say) PHP? It'd be far easier to just have PHP embed an extra class on the nodes you want highlighted and not try to dynamically insert style sheets as you are

Comment: In general I think your solution is better suited by creating a style sheet, of which you make a series of styles for various classes, id's, and so on.. then your needs may better be met with an addition of something like jQuery. Where you can add/remove classes with ease. Rather than having multiple locations with your styling through out javascript not only just taking up extra room, but in the event your using the same styling in many of places and want to make a change thats going over everything one by one to do so. Where with CSS one change on place handles them all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#banner{text-align:center;}
#banner>img{width:960px;height:187.5px;}
#nav>.selected{background-image:url('images/gradients/transparent_gradient.png');}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="banner"><img src="images/fullbanner.png"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="navbar">
<ul id="nav">
<li id="nav_index"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li id="nav_archive"><a href="index.php?site=news&action=archive">News</a></li>
<li id="nav_squads"><a href="index.php?site=squads">Roster</a></li>
<li id="nav_forum"><a href="index.php?site=forum">Forums</a></li>
<li id="nav_about"><a href="index.php?site=about">Contact</a></li>
</ul> 
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('nav_'+window.location.href.split('=')[1]).className='selected';
</script>
```

You shouldn't use `<center>`, it's deprecated!

Instead of writing a style sheet with javascript in order to match an element, you should match a class and then only add that class to your element with javascript.

And I don't understand very well your code:

```
function parseUrl( url ) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    return a;
}

var page=parseUrl('').search
```

It gives `""` to me, but I have never seen `.search` on an anchor... If you want to get the current URL, you can do `window.location.href`.

And another point: if you use `var` outside functions (in global scope) you are creating a global variable, which won't be deleted and uses memory. Then, you can remove it when you don't want to use it anymore (`var a="dagjhdjgailghkagh";/*code*/;a=null;`), or use a self-execute function (closure) which contains your code.

**Edit:**

Sorry, instead of `#nav>selected` I meant `#nav>.selected`.

You can see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/VhWHp/

(But the url doesn't have `=`, so I replace it manually to 'archive'. In your site, remove that line)

And yes, it loads CSS first and then the nav. But that's the true power of CSS and javascript: if you set a class to an element after it has been loaded, that element will have the styles applied to that class.

**Edit 2:**

The problem is that if you do `split('=')[1]`, the result will be something like `"news&action"` instead of `"news"`.

Then, you could use a function I wrote some time ago:

```
function sQuery(arg) {
  if(window.location.search){
    var que = window.location.search.substring(1);
    if(arg=='string'){return que;}
    que = que.split("&");
    if(!arg||arg=='array'){return que;}
    for(var i=0;i<que.length;i++){
      var qvar = que[i].split("=");
      if(qvar[0]==arg){
        return qvar[1];
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Then, call the function like this: `sQuery('site')`

```
document.getElementById('nav_'+(sQuery('site')||'index')).className='selected';
```

You can also call `sQuery('array')` or just `sQuery()` if you want to get `["site=news","action=archive"]`, and `sQuery('string')` if you want `"site=news&action=archive"`. If you won't use that, you can simplify the function:

```
function sQuery(arg) {
  if(window.location.search){
    var que = window.location.search.substring(1).split("&");
    for(var i=0;i<que.length;i++){
      var qvar = que[i].split("=");
      if(qvar[0]==arg){
        return qvar[1];
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Not working for me, did you try it live? I see where you're going with this but I'm not smart enough to fix it :P

Comment: isn't it loading the css before renaming that selected nav?

Comment: @user1361154 What does your URLs look like? Does `window.location.href.split('=')[1]` work?

Comment: @Orion that should work for some of them, not all of them. The urls are in the OP

Comment: Then you could use `var url=window.location.href.split('=')[1]||'index',el=document.getElementById('nav_'+url);if(el){el.className='selected'}`. What's OP?

Comment: Original post, :P - and ya ill try that now